# Cached integers, the `is` operator and `id()` in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.7

I used to show something like `print(5 is 7 - 2, 300 is 302 - 2)` in my Python talks when talking about some Python trivia. Today I realised that this example yields a (to me) unexpected result when ran in Python 3.7.

We know that the numbers from -5 to 255 are cached internally [Python 3 docs - PyLong_FromLong](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong) which can be found in earlier API docs too.

The `is` operator (as described in the docs [Python 3 docs - is operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is)) tests the object identity, i.e. it uses the `id()` function to determine that and yields `True` when the values match.

The `id()` function is guaranteed to return a unique and constant value for an object during its lifetime (also described in the docs [Python 3 docs - id()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)).

All these rules gives you the following results (as many Python coders know):

Python 2.7:

```
>>> print(5 is 7 - 2, 300 is 302 - 2)
True False
```

Python 3.6:

```
>>> print(5 is 7 - 2, 300 is 302 - 2)
True False
```

However, Python 3.7 behaves differently:

```
>>> print(5 is 7 - 2, 300 is 302 - 2)
True True
```

I tried to understand why, but I couldn't find any hints in the Python sources yet...

`id(302 - 2)` always yields a different value, so I am wondering why `302 - 2 is 300` yields `True`. How does the `is` operator know that the values are the same? Is this somehow overloaded for integer comparisons in Python 3.7?

```
>>> id(300)
140059023515344

>>> id(302 - 2)
140059037091600

>>> id(300) is id(302 - 2)
False

>>> 300 is 302 - 2
True

>>> id(300) == id(302 -2)
True

>>> id(302 - 2)
140059037090320

>>> id(302 - 2)
140059023514640
```

Comment: Per [note 4](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#id20) *"Due to automatic garbage-collection, free lists, and the dynamic nature of descriptors, you may notice seemingly unusual behaviour in certain uses of the is operator, like those involving comparisons between instance methods, or constants. Check their documentation for more info."* **But** I checked, the int docs of and integer part of standard types and found nothing that really answers this. Be nice to find an answer

Comment: Thanks for that, it's good to have this reference here :) user2357112 already answered the question, see below!

Comment: That's the thing with implementation details. They are subject to change. In this case, the compiler changed, in that it switched from a peephole optimiser to one that optimises the generated AST. See `import dis; dis.dis.dis(compile('print(5 is 7 - 2, 300 is 302 - 2)', '', 'single'))` to see what effect that has on your sample. Pay close attention to the index number after each `LOAD_CONST` opcode..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`is` hasn't changed. No part of the language semantics have changed; whether the objects you're comparing are the same object was never specified behavior. The two sides of your `is` comparison simply happen to be the same object now. This is an effect of a change in constant folding optimization.

Initial generation of a code object's `co_consts` reuses a single object for equivalent atomic constants. (I say "equivalent" instead of "equal" because 1 and 1.0 aren't equivalent.) This is a different effect from the caching of integers from -5 to 256, and it only applies within a single code object. [Previously](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Python/peephole.c#L347), the compile-time optimization pass that converts `302 - 2` to `300` happened in the bytecode peephole optimizer, which kicks in after initial `co_consts` generation, and doesn't do the same constant reuse.

In CPython 3.7, this optimization pass was [moved](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/7ea143ae795a9fd57eaccf490d316bdc13ee9065) from the bytecode peephole optimizer to a new AST optimizer. The AST optimizer takes effect before initial generation of a code object's `co_consts`, so constant reuse now applies to the results.

---

You can see the effects of constant reuse on old Python versions by doing something like

```
>>> 300 is 300
True
```

which produces `True` even on CPython 2.7 or 3.6, despite 300 being outside the range of the small integer cache. You can prevent constant reuse by ensuring that the constants you're comparing end up in separate code objects:

```
>>> (lambda: 300)() is 300
False
```

This produces `False` on any version of CPython, even with the new optimizer changes. However, it produces `True` on PyPy, because PyPy has its own optimization behavior, and PyPy behaves as if all equal integers are represented by the same integer object.

Comment: Ah makes sense.. Could have thought about the constant folding. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: run `import dis; dis.dis(compile('print(5 is 7 - 2, 300 is 302 - 2)', '', 'single'))` and it would have jumped out immediately. :-)

Comment: That's true Martijn ;)

Comment: In all Python versions, you'll see that `LOAD_CONST` loads folded constants, it just so happens that the new optimiser knows to produce just one constant, not two, for equivalent values. You can see this from the constant index that `LOAD_CONST` loads from.